Exceution of simple Javascript in Rails app doesn't work
I am new to this topic and online resources didnt help. I am trying to set up a simple button which onClick executes something in JavaScript. I wanted to implement on the front-end to add html to the DOM. It seems I am doing something wrong with regards to referencing the programmed JS Code.

I modified my application.js to add require("./invoices/invoice_positions"):
// present in this directory. You're encouraged to place your actual application logic in
// a relevant structure within app/javascript and only use these pack files to reference
// that code so it'll be compiled.

require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("popper.js")
require("bootstrap")
require("jquery")
require("inputmask")
require("channels")
require('./nested_forms/addFields')
require('./nested_forms/removeFields')

require("./invoices/form")
require("./invoices/select")
require("./payments/form")
require("./header_menu")
require("./invoices/invoice_positions")
// Uncomment to copy all static images under ../images to the output folder and reference
// them with the image_pack_tag helper in views (e.g <%= image_pack_tag 'rails.png' %>)
// or the `imagePath` JavaScript helper below.
//
// const images = require.context('../images', true)
// const imagePath = (name) => images(name, true)



I added the function under app/javascript/invoices/invoice_positions.js with some dummy code:


function increaseInvoicePositions() {window.alert("BAM");}


I added this to my view because of some online help:

<%= content_for :head do %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "/invoices/invoice_positions" %>
<% end %>


I added this button to the view:

<%= button_tag t('invoice_positions.increase'), type: "button", onclick: "increaseInvoicePositions()", class: "btn btn-secondary" %>

Result
In theory after reloading the page I assume it works but it fails with a browser error in Chrome. I restarted the server but it didnt help. What am I missing?


I think you need to solve the first error (in select.js) first, b/c the second one may be a result of the first.

In order to call a function from the an inline attribute it would have to be in the global scope. Just don't. Attach an event handler and don't waste time learning JS the wrong way. https://javascript.info/event-delegation


no clue what your comment means @max.
LesNightingill Not sure where this select.js thingy comes from


@max is saying don't use the inline onClick element event. Instead add an event handler to your JS. Here are the jQuery Docs for the click event.

@Julian yes. What I'm saying is that inline event handlers (like the onClick attribute) have been know to be problematic for 20+ years. One of the big issues is that they can only access the global scope (window) which makes namespace collisions very likely. You're incorrectly assuming here that the code you're requiring through the assets pipeline will work just like if you linked to the file directly via a script tag or a inline script tag and place the function in the global scope - which it doesn't do by design.

While you can "fix" your code by for example doing window.increaseInvoicePositions = function() {window.alert("BAM");} to explicitly make it a global you're really just footgunning yourself by approaching JS like its 1995.
